# Where should I put launch folder?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [launch file tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Launch-system.html), I am a little confused where should I put this `launch` folder, and what is the content of this folder?

Can someone help clarify? Thanks!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410994/where-should-i-put-launch-folder?/) by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2023-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Hongbo Miao, I am not sure why the launch folder is not shown in the tutorial but it will be inside the package `py_launch_example` After that, the launch file script that you will write later will be put inside this launch folder.

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2023-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) on 2023-01-01**:
Thanks @Robo_guy ! I opened a pull request to update the document at https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/3264
Please correct if I am wrong, thanks!

**Comment by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on 2023-01-02**:
Yes I checked, it is correct